# SQL Server 2008 R2 become slow after some minutes from the start

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a sql server 2008R2 with a database that have table with thousands of rows. When i start the server execute fast this query:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT *, [t0].[distance] AS [Meters], @p4 AS [ToWhat]
FROM [dbo].[getEventsByRange](@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3) AS [t0]
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Event] AS [t1] ON [t0].[idEvent] = [t1].[id]
ORDER BY [t0].[distance]',N'@p0 var
```

where getEventsByRange is this function:

```
SELECT idEvent, geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(' + @userLongitude + ' ' +       @userLatitude + ')', 4326).STDistance([Coordinates]) as distance
FROM EventCoords
INNER JOIN Event ON EventCoords.idEvent = Event.id
WHERE DAY(start_time)=DAY(@timeMax) AND MONTH(start_time)=MONTH(@timeMax)AND
YEAR(start_time)=YEAR(@timeMax) and 
geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(' + @userLongitude + ' ' + @userLatitude + ')', 4326).STDistance([Coordinates]) < @maxDistance
```

After some minutes this query become very slow to execute. Where is the problem? Why when the server haven't query cached go fast?

Comment: Did you have a chance to try the OPTION (RECOMPILE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be that Parameter Sniffing is causing the reuse of a suboptimal cached execution plan ?

To see if this is the case and OPTION (RECOMPILE) to the end of your query:

```
ORDER BY [t0].[distance]
OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

If the queries stay performant (and thus the problem is parameter sniffing) we can make some better recommendations

Comment: @Marco OPTION (RECOMPILE) did solve the problem? Than it was parameter sniffing. By adding that clause you disable execution plan caching which can cause, oddly enough, performance degradation. Did your research it and are aware of the effect? If not I can go deeper on it.